# Views title is blank

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using the Drupal views module to create an overview of nodes. In the view i created i configured the Title. But now when the page is rendered the title isn't shown. It is shown in the breadcrumb etc. But not in the grid template, also if i use another template it still doesn't show. Any idea what this can be? I tried looking for it, but my experience with Drupal is very limited.

I checked the drupal_get_title etc. and it is always returning the title, i think something goes wrong in the views module, but i don't know what :s

Kind regards,
Daan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely how you print the page title. If you want it to happen globally, you should print it in the `page.tpl.php`. Have you inspected the `$title` variable in the page template? That is what it's usually called.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and the `$title` var is empty. The default views template is trying to print the `$title` var, but it doesn't pass the `if ($title)` test.

Answer (score 0):

i idd removed the title from page.tpl.php, but i did this because i thought it should be printed in the views template. When you check views-view-unformatted.tpl.php etc you see this:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

so i thought $title would print the title, but it is fixed just by adding it in my page.tpl.php